# HTML input range Style in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I´ve got a CSS problem with a input-range element:

```
<input type="range" id="difficultSelect" max="3" min="1" value="2"/>
```

the css looks like this:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
z-index: 102;
width: 225px;
height: 5px;
margin-left: 95px;
margin-top: 15px;
border-radius: 2px;

background: linear-gradient(to right,  #83f922 0%,#ff4c00 100%); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#83f922), 
    color-stop(100%,#ff4c00)); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #83f922 0%, #ff4c00 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #83f922 0%,#ff4c00 100%);
```

As u can see, the background of the slider should show a linear-gradient from green to red.
In Chrome it displays as intended, but in Firefox there is the background-gradient, but ontop of it is the normal "grey" bar of the slider: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Z7Y.jpg

Were is my mistake? Firefox Version ist 27.0.1

THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mozilla has a separate property to style the shadow dom of the input (which is what `-webkit-appearance:none;` takes care of for webkit):

```
::-moz-range-track {background:transparent; border:0px;}
```

On a side note, you can also style the slide/grip/button/thumb:

```
/* These need to be separated, not combined with a comma */
::-webkit-slider-thumb { /* ... */}
::-moz-range-thumb  { /* ... */}
```

Comment: Not sure why CSS doesn't allow comma combination.